# Aspose - remove w:hint from word

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose.words

I use 18.3 aspose version.

I need use function JoinRunsWithSameFormatting .
But same runs have , and run near them doesn't. 
How can I remove  from all runs of document.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not actually clear what you need to achieve. but I suspect you need to clear formatting of all runs and then join them together. If so, you can use [Font.ClearFormatting](https://apireference.aspose.com/net/words/aspose.words/font/methods/clearformatting) method to achieve this.

Disclosure: I work at Aspose.Words team.